# First Order Logic - Formalization and Correctness

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

I'm having some problems with the formalization in FOL. 
I'll start with an example:

''  Every  state has a capital but city capital of two different states exists''

I'll give you my answer with how i interpreted the phrase:

$ ( \forall (x) . ( \exists (y) . state(x) \to ( city(y) \land capital (y,x))) \land \lnot (\exists (y). ( \exists (z). \exists (h) . ( city(y) \to (state (z) \land (capital(y,z)) \land (city (y) \to (state (h) \land capital (y,h))) $

I interpreted like: for everystate, a city exists and this city is a capital of the state. And, there aren's two sames city that are the capital for one country.
 My problems are: generally, how do i prove if my answer is correct? What laws should i use to prove it? Because my professor had a simpler and more elegant answer than me, but i thought mine, even if longer, thought i was correct, but i can't prove it.
Obviously this question does apply in all my other exercises. I've done alot of pages of them, but i don't generally know how to check them. 
So:
- *How to i check that my phrase is correct?*
- *Any tips and tricks?*

Comment: Quatifiers are related to connectives as follows:

Comment: *tips and tricks*: proceed step-by-step. "Every state has a capital" will be $\forall x \ (state(x) \to \exists y \ (city(y) \land capital (y,x)))$.

Comment: We can prove that this is equivalent to: $∀x \ ∃y \ (state(x) → (city(y) ∧ capital(y,x)))$.

Comment: "but" is $\land$: correct; thus, formalize the second clause and "join them". Second clause: "city capital of two different states exists'' ?

Comment: Translating it from italian to english may have changed the interpretation. Ultimately, it is implying that: if two cities are a capital, then no state exists with two capitals!

Comment: If so, I would say: "no city is capital of two different states' :-)'

Comment: How about $ \lnot ( x = y) $ ? When should i use something like that?

Comment: It is also written $x \ne y$; we have to use it when we want to "impose" the constraint that variables $x$ and $y$ will refer to different things. E.g."there are at least two philosphers" will be $\exists x \ \exists y \  (Phil(x) \land Phil(y) \land x \ne y)$.

Comment: So it reads like: philosofer x is different from philosofer y? Could it be used like: if x has something in common with z and y, then $ \lnot (z=y) $ ?

Comment: @bram28  If you'd like, we can discuss this in [Constructive Feedback chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43593/constructive-feedback)

Comment: Do mean: Every state has a capital, but there exists two different states with the same capital? If so then you would have: $\forall a: [State(a) \implies \exists b:[City (b) \land Capital(b,a)]] \land \exists a,b,c: [State(a)\land State(b) \land City(c) \land a\neq b \land Capital(c,a)\land Capital (c,b)]$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Quantifiers are related to logical connectives as follows: $\forall x(x\in A\rightarrow P(x))$ and $\exists y(y\in B\wedge Q(y))$.

Comment: Hey thanks, that is a hint i actually did read after the post and it does change a lot in the way i formalize! Other question would be: in what cases i have to include $ \not (x=y) $ ? I saw it in another post, but i didn't understand all of it! And how do i check my phrase?